# Print Text which is in a text Box PYTHON SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium

im trying to print out text which is in a textbox, the HTML for the text box is:

```
<input type="text" class="fillIn" disabled="disabled" spellcheck="false" style="width: 36px;">
```

[image: df here]

I am trying to print it on the terminal like this
[image]

but i am unable to, I have tried input.get_attribute('value')
but that doesn't seem to work either. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: i forgot to say that its a box on a webpage, im using selenium.

Comment: Sorry but you have created textbox in HTML or any python GUI ?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to include, but its on a site im using selenium webdriver.

Comment: The HTML that you have shared has `disabled` attribute.. Can you share URL ? or bit more outer HTML ?

Comment: the link is https://www.ixl.com/math/algebra-1/convert-between-decimals-and-fractions when you get the answer incorrectly the text box appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:-

```
inpValue = "-4"
inputElm = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@class='fillIn']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", inputElm)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '"+inpValue + "'", inputElm)

print(inputElm.get_attribute("value"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So just consider we entered `Example` in input box

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
#identify element
l= driver.find_element_by_name("q")
l.send_keys("q")
#get_attribute() to get value of input box
print("Value of input box: " + l.get_attribute('value'))
driver.close()
```

I think it can solve your problem since you use selenium and it will return to you `Example`

[You can check entire topic from this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/get-value-of-an-input-box-using-selenium-python)

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it didnt work. Have a nice day!